# Chrome extension: Injecting a fixed header into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension which I'd like to inject a visible header (i.e., a nav-bar-style header, not a header in the http-sense) into certain pages.

For most webpages, the code works. I'm using [this (wicked cool) project](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/crossbuilder), which uses react/redux code to enable simple extension/webpage communication.

The location of the inserted code is dictated by this line, which, as written, inserts the `div` containing my header as the first child in the DOM `body`:

```
document.body.insertBefore(injectDiv, document.body.firstChild);
```

So far, problems emerge when the site has either a) a fixed header, or b) a floating popup that hovers over the injected header.

Is there  way to insert my DOM node such that it pushes the *entire* contents of the DOM down? Almost like the browser-bars that Yahoo et al sneak into IE sometimes.

I don't really know jQuery, so I thought maybe there was a trick in that toolbox, but vanilla javascript would be ideal.

ETA: I haven't fully designed the header yet, so the only CSS props it has are those related to positioning:

```
  let injectDiv = document.createElement('div');
    injectDiv.style.border = '1px solid #ccc';
    injectDiv.style.background='white';
    injectDiv.style.textAlign = 'center';
    injectDiv.style.width = '100%';
    injectDiv.style.zIndex = 10011;
    injectDiv.style.top = 0;
    injectDiv.style.left = 0;
    injectDiv.style.display = 'block';
    injectDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
```

where `z-index = (target site's highest z-index) + 1`

Comment: Could you please provide more css code about your inserted header? Maybe that will help

Comment: sure! i define style w/in the javascript, so it's pretty straightforward & minimal.

Comment: since with `position: fixed`, the element is positioned relative to the window, I don't think you can really move this kind of element down. However, what about getting all these element then changing it's `top` property by adding `Your header height + Your header top`?

Comment: @Brandon Did you manage to get this working in the end? I've trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Michael look into `position: sticky`